# Play: errors with a yml file

Tags: java, playframework, runtime-error, yaml

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Java.

I've a Role class that's look like the following:

```
public class Role {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> create;
    private ArrayList<String> read;
    private ArrayList<String> update;
    private ArrayList<String> delete;
    private ArrayList<String> pages;
    private ArrayList<String> modules;
    private List<String> modulesAuth;



    public Role(String name, ArrayList<String> create, ArrayList<String> read,
            ArrayList<String> update, ArrayList<String> delete, ArrayList<String> modules,
            List<String> modulesAuth) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.create = create;
        this.read = read;
        this.update = update;
        this.delete = delete;
        this.modules = modules;
        this.modulesAuth = modulesAuth;
        this.pages = null;
    }

    public boolean canCreate(String resourceName) {
        if (create == null)
            return false;
        return create.contains(resourceName);
    }

    public boolean canDelete(String resourceName) {
        if (delete == null)
            return false;
        return delete.contains(resourceName);
    }

    public boolean canRead(String resourceName) {
        if (read == null)
            return false;
        return read.contains(resourceName);
    }

    public boolean canUpdate(String resourceName) {
        if (update == null)
            return false;
        return update.contains(resourceName);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCreate() {
        return create;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDelete() {
        return delete;
    }

    public List<String> getModules() {
        return modules;
    }

    public List<String> getModulesAuth() {
        return modulesAuth;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getRead() {
        return read;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getUpdate() {
        return update;
    }

    public void setCreate(ArrayList<String> create) {
        this.create = create;
    }

    public void setDelete(ArrayList<String> delete) {
        this.delete = delete;
    }

    public void setModules(ArrayList<String> modules) {
        this.modules = modules;
    }

    public void setModulesAuth(List<String> modulesAuth) {
        this.modulesAuth = modulesAuth;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPages(ArrayList<String> pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public void setRead(ArrayList<String> read) {
        this.read = read;
    }

    public void setUpdate(ArrayList<String> update) {
        this.update = update;
    }

}
```

I've a yml files that's look like the following:

```
roles:
    - !!bdrim.models.Role
        name:     Super Administrator

        create:
                - users
                - companies
                - roles
                - pages
                - company users
                - company shops

        read:
                - users
                - companies
                - roles
                - pages
                - company users
                - company shops
                - company charts
                - modules

        update:
                - users
                - companies
                - roles
                - pages
                - company users
                - company shops

        delete:
                - users
                - companies
                - roles
                - pages
                - company users
                - company shops

        modules:
                - mailchimp
                - recommendation system
        modulesAuth:
                - mailchimp
                - recommendation system
        pages:
                - users
                - companies
                - roles
                - pages
                - company users
                - company shops
                - company charts
```

My `Global` class called this yml file.
But when I try to start my server an exception occurred:

```
[error] application - 

! @6k0h3h3fp - Internal server error, for (GET) [/modules] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ConstructorException: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:bdrim.models.Role; exception=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bdrim.models.Role.<init>();  in 'reader', line 132, column 7:
        - !!bdrim.models.Role
          ^]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:151) ~[play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115) ~[play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115) ~[play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:113) ~[play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.ConstructorException: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:bdrim.models.Role; exception=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bdrim.models.Role.<init>();  in 'reader', line 132, column 7:
        - !!bdrim.models.Role
          ^
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:336) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructSequenceStep2(BaseConstructor.java:275) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructSequence(BaseConstructor.java:246) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlSeq.construct(SafeConstructor.java:442) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bdrim.models.Role.<init>()
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.createEmptyJavaBean(Constructor.java:219) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:189) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:332) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructSequenceStep2(BaseConstructor.java:275) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bdrim.models.Role.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.createEmptyJavaBean(Constructor.java:215) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:189) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:332) ~[snakeyaml-1.13.jar:na]
```

What's wrong??
When i skip the modules part of the `yml` all works good.

Comment: Class `Role` is missing default constructor.

Comment: @MonCalamari I've added the default constructor, but nothing is changed.

Comment: Try making Role a static class : public static Role{...}

Comment: @Moebius Role is not an inner class..